# Trying to use Ajax in Rails for the first time: Controller rendering empty document?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I have a page rendering a list of `Ideas`. Each item has a Claim button next to it. What *should* happen is that the user click the Claim button, `Idea#claim` controller action runs, and the Claim button goes dim.

What *actually* happens is... nothing. Not even a Rails error page, which is why I'm stuck. Relevant snippets follow:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :ideas do 
    collection do
      post 'claim'
    end
  end
```

**ideas_controller#claim**

```
  def claim
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    current_user.claim(@idea)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render :nothing => true } 
    end
  end
```

**_idea.html.erb partial**

```
<span class="idea-actions" id=<%="idea"+idea.id.to_s%>>
    <%= link_to "Claim", {method: "post", action: "claim", idea_id: idea.id}, {class: 'claim', remote: true}  %>
</span>
```

**ideas.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('.claim').bind 'ajax:success', ->
    alert 'Ajax success!'
```

This is absolutely my first time trying to do something like this, and my CoffeeScript/JS is virtually nonexistent. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:** Moved code from application.js to ideas.js.coffee, switched form using `button_to` to `link_to`. Changes shown in code above. Right now, when I click the link, absolutely nothing happens. Still no joy! :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move `remote: true` to `html_options` part of `button_to`

```
<%= button_to "Claim", {action: "claim", idea_id: idea.id}, {remote: true, class: 'btn btn-small claim'}  %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: I did that (and changed to link_to, and made a few other changes) but it still doesn't work. Can you look at the code changes above and see if you have any other insights? Thank you!

Comment: Ah! I had to move the POST action to the HTML options as well! I think I'm on the right track now!

Answer (score 0):

Modified the button_to to be cleaner:

```
<%= button_to "Claim", claim_ideas_path(id: idea.id, format: 'js'),  remote: true  %>
```

That should do it..